# Gulp custom function returning parallel won't do anything

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, gulp, config

I'm trying to implement an abstraction layer over the Gulp API by allowing easy configuration over a dedicated file.

To sum it up, I have a function (`builder`) that requires that file (`gulpconfig.js`) and calls functions that return `ReadableStream`s from an object the config file exports with `parallel()`.

Here's the [gist](https://gist.github.com/GitGangGuy/20bf9ceabf660235b315a790b84b0c56) (simplified from my private source).

However, when I do `gulp build`, it doesn't call the `TestHandler` function as it should. After debugging for a while, I have identified that everything (including variable assignments etc) work perfectly fine, but it just won't execute the returned `parallel()` instance.

How can I fix this behaviour?

Here are the code snippets from GitHub Gist:

`gulpfile.js`:

```
/* REQUIRES */
const { parallel } = require('gulp');
const user = require('./gulpconfig');

let params = {};
let fns = [];

async function builder() {
    for (let [name, props] of Object.entries(user.config)) {
        let fnName = name;
        let fn = user[fnName];
        let src = props.src;
        let dest = props.dest;
        params[fnName] = { src, dest };
        fns.push(fn);
    }
    user.paramCp(params);
    return parallel(...fns);
}
exports.build = builder;
```

`gulpconfig.js`:

```
/* REQUIRES */
const { src, dest, on, watch } = require('gulp');
const pipeline = require('readable-stream');
/* USER CONFIG */
exports.config = {
    testHandler: {
        src: "./input/*",
        dest: "./output/",
    },
};
/* LOCAL PARAM HANDLER. USED INTERNALLY. */
var params;
exports.paramCp = _params => {
    params = _params;
};
var tSrc;
var tDest;
function getParams() {
    let obj = params[getParams.caller.name];
    tSrc = obj.src;
    tDest = obj.dest;
}
/* HANDLERS. DEFINED BY handler KEY IN CONFIG */
exports.testHandler = function testHandler() {
    getParams(); // You can now use tSrc and tDest
    return pipeline(src(tSrc), dest(tDest));
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is expected for Gulp.

`gulp.parallel` and `gulp.series` return functions (which will concurrently and serially execute their arguments, respectively). They are meant to be used in task *definitions* (where a function is expected) or called directly.

See [this GitHub issue](https://github.com/gulpjs/gulp/issues/1093) for more details and explanation.

#### Solution

Execute the function returned by `parallel`

```
    return parallel(...fns)();
```

#### Additional issue: problem with `pipeline`

It looks like you're trying to use [`pipeline`](https://nodejs.org/docs/latest-v12.x/api/stream.html#stream_stream_pipeline_streams_callback) here, which is not a bad idea, but your `pipeline` variable is not correctly defined. 
`const pipeline = require('readable-stream');` makes `pipeline` of type [`Readable`](https://nodejs.org/docs/latest-v12.x/api/stream.html#stream_class_stream_readable). This is the [default export of the `readable-stream` package](https://github.com/nodejs/readable-stream/blob/e02fcbbfe3b297038dce2d81a65a66709f8b8de9/readable.js#L7).

You probably want this

```
const { pipeline } = require('readable-stream');
```

Comment: Thanks, but now it says `(WARN) testHandler: No handler exported. Won't execute this task`. It seemingly still doesn't get the pipeline back from the testHandler function to execute it.

Comment: I see another few issues with the code, though most are style-based. It also looks like you're using `pipeline` wrong. I'll update the answer

Comment: I've updated the answer. Additionally, i'd suggest cleaning up the code a bit by **1)** using `let` and `const` exclusively (no `var`), **2)** use destructuring instead of creating additional variables, **3)** don't redeclare variables under a different name (e.g. `let fnName = name;`, just call the variable `fnName` to begin with), **4)** bind the function parameters (`fns.push(fn.bind(user, ...params)`) instead of trying to setting them in a closure at some distant time before the call (`user.paramCp(params);`), which is hacky and error-prone

Comment: Actually, I've been using the `{ pipeline }` import all along im my private codebase, sorry about that mistake :/ Again, the gist source is strongly simplified. In my real source, I'm actually doing something with the function name (regarding point 3) and I've also declared everything with const/let, but thanks for the last one, wouldn'tve thought about that! Anyways, I'm still facing the same error; any ideas?

Comment: I'm not sure where that error comes from, it does not appear to be a Gulp error. The simplified version of the code doesn't provide any insight so I am not sure I'll be able to provide any additional assistance.

Comment: Consider accepting this answer (since it resolves the question), reworking the simplified code to show the new problem, and posting a new question explaining the new problem.

Comment: If you're worried about not getting the bounty, don't worry ;)

Comment: haha I am not worried :) Just not sure I have time or am even able to help any longer. New question tends to help with visibility in terms of allowing others to help solve the problem. But yes, thanks for the bounty. If you do post another question, link it here and I'll have a look